# unreproducible exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I've updated my app to Rails version 3.2.15 a few days ago.
I'm using ruby MRI 2.0.0-p247.

Since the rails upgrade, every now and then my app raises  unreproducible exceptions.

Here a couple of examples:

> TypeError: wrong argument type Proc (expected Proc)
>
> Tick TypeError in XXXX, wrong argument type Time (expected time)

When I execute the same request, with same user, and same params, everything works well.

Those exceptions happened really rarely, 2 or 3 in total in a 3 weeks range period.

I've no clue where to start digging to be honest....

Anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: what do you mean "unpronounceable exceptions"??

Comment: that the exception is raised, but it can't be reproduced in any way, with same code base, same server, same session, same everything...

Comment: sorry just realized the typo! eewwww .  unreproducible! stupid corrector... I change the title

Comment: @CLod I get exceptions like this too, and I'm stumped.  Did you ever resolve your issues?

Comment: @jemminger sorry I never updated this issue. It has been a while and I can't remember the precise details, but it was something around a memory leak with libxml used by nokogiri (in my case). Try to update all your OS xml libraries and recompile nokogiri or any native C gems that use them.